# How to distinguish java map from clojure map?

Tags: dictionary, clojure, clojure-java-interop

Let's say I have the following code:

```
(def m1 (java.util.HashMap.))
(def m2 (java.util.LinkedHashMap.))
(def m3 {})
```

I need a function that will allow me to detect maps that came from java, e.g.:

```
(map java-map? [m1 m2 m3]) ;; => (true true false)
```

Anything out of the box?

Comment: Have you tried using `type`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i would do this:

```
user=> (defn java-map? [m] 
         (and (instance? java.util.Map m) 
              (not (map? m))))
#'user/java-map?

user=> (java-map? {})
false

user=> (java-map? (java.util.HashMap.))
true

user=> (java-map? [])
false
```

so you just check that it implements core java's `Map` interface, but not being a clojure's persistent map.

Comment: This seems legit to me.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`map?`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map_q) to check if something implements `IPersistentMap` which is true for Clojure maps but not for `java.utils.*` maps:

```
(map? (java.util.HashMap.)) ;; => false
(map? (java.util.LinkedHashMap.)) ;; => false
(map? {}) ;; => true
```

To be more precise you should rather check if a given object meets some requirements (e.g. is persistent, immutable/mutable - `map?` will answer that specific question). There is no easy way to tell if you got a Java implementation of a map as you could get any other implementation from external library which might have a custom implementation of `java.util.Map` or extending one of the concrete implementations from `java.util` package.

Comment: Yes, was actually thinking about of usage of `map?`, but `(def java-map? (complement map?))` - this will give incorrect result on objects of other types: `(java-map? []) ;; => true`

Comment: Yes, you are correct, let me remove that part of the answer as it is incorrect.

Comment: I believe, there You also could use a `protocol` or `multimethods` to dispatch by input type